# How to make API calls from a .NET Application to an Ethereum Private Network

Tags: web3js, blockchain, external-api, .net

I'm starting on blockchain development and I have a question:

I was wondering if it is possible to make RPC calls to a private ethereum network (handling user private keys is not a problem in our scenario) from a ASP.NET MVC application using web3js for example (or maybe other framework/library more suitable).

The calls would have as objectives sending tokens from one user to the other and checking a given user's balance.

Thanks in advance for your answers!!

Kind Regards,
Daniel Costa

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's indeed possible! [Nethereum](https://nethereum.com/) aims to bring web3.js functionality to .Net

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

So, if I understood correctly, I can have my .net web site outside Ethereum and use Nethereum to make my async calls to push transactions?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You could use Nethereum to enable your .Net application to interact with an Ethereum node, and smart contracts deployed on Ethereum

Comment: @danielcostaext if this answers your question then please accept it by clicking on tick icon.